# Exception: System.DllNotFoundException - Invoke CoolProp (Native C++ library) functions with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, shared-libraries, pinvoke, c#-native-library

I have a .NET project written in C# that has a dependency with the CoolProp library (available here https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp). It calls the CoolProp functions using PInvoke.

Unluckily I have to run this program in a linux environment (precisely the AWS lambda env https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

For now, I want to execute it with .NET core (command `dotnet run`) on my PC with Ubuntu OS but I get always the following error:

`Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: 
Unable to load shared library 'libCoolProp.so' or one of its dependencies. 
In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibCoolProp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Test1.Program.PropsSI(String Output, String Name1, Double Prop1, String Name2, Double Prop2, String Ref)
   at Test1.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/user/Desktop/TestDllInUbuntu/Test1/Program.cs:line 23`

The test program is:

```
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test1 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        [DllImport("libCoolProp.so")] 
        private static extern double PropsSI(string Output, string Name1, double Prop1, string Name2, double Prop2, string Ref); 

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            double propsRes = PropsSI("H", "T", 300.0, "Q", 0.0, "R410A"); 
            Console.WriteLine(propsRes); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The `Program.cs` is in the same folder of `libCoolProp.so`.

*Notes:*

- The same program in Windows 10 compiled and executed with *.Net Core* with its `libCoolProp.dll` works.
- The same program in Ubuntu 18 compiled and executed with *Mono Runtime* works.

How to solve the compatibility issue between CoolProp lib and .Net Core runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The executable file build by .NET core is inside `bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1/`, hence is sufficient to link the library with the correct path:

```
[DllImport("../../../libCoolProp.so")]
```

This is not necessary for Windows 10 as the .NET core runtime search the `dll` inside the folder in which the command `dotnet run` is called.

For more info look up the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2015

Comment: While this does work, this is not ideal. I am personally a bit concerned about the fact that adding a .so as an EmbeddedResource in .csproj file does not cause it to be part of the build. It is unclear if this is a debug build problem, and maybe release has it (and debug misses it), but there must be a smart way to get your .so and DLL files to part of your executable

Comment: Yes, that was for an accademic project. Today I will definitely go with the .csproj file in which you can put `<None Include="libCoolProp.so" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />`. This should copy the libCoolProp.so file in your bin/debug/netcoreapp/ directory hence you only need to write `[DllImport("libCoolProp")]` (but I did't test it)